# Two way data binding with directive and isolate scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to understand directives, and I'm having problems with two way data binding.

My directive will be used to submit a form when "enter" is pressed in a textarea.

I found a solution in [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13690238/2269705) (see the code below in the scope definition of the directive), but I don't like it because it means that if I change the model name, I need to change the directive as well..

--> [Here is the problem in codepen.io](http://codepen.io/y__b__y/pen/afFec)

Here is the html part:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <textarea ng-model="foo" enter-submit="submit()"></textarea><br/>
  Binding: {{foo}}
</div>
```

Here is the javascript part:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

function MyController($scope) {

  $scope.foo = "bar"

  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log("Submitting form");
  }
}

app.directive('enterSubmit', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        submitFn: '&enterSubmit',
        foo: '=ngModel'      // <------------------- dont't like this solution
      },
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        elem.bind('keydown', function(event) {
          var code = event.keyCode || event.which;

          if (code === 13) {
            if (!event.shiftKey) {
              event.preventDefault();
              scope.submitFn();
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You have to couple the variable assignment anyway at some point. You won't get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When multiple directives are used on an element, normally you don't want any of them to use an isolate scope, since that forces all of them to use the isolate scope.  In particular, isolate scopes should not be used with ng-model – see [Can I use ng-model with isolated scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896732/ngmodel-and-component-with-isolated-scope).

I suggest creating no new scope (the default, i.e., `scope: false`):

```
app.directive('enterSubmit', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      //scope: {
      //  submitFn: '&enterSubmit',
      //  foo: '=ngModel' // <------------------- dont't like this solution
      //},
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('keydown', function(event) {
          var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
          if (code === 13) {
            if (!event.shiftKey) {
              event.preventDefault();
              scope.$apply(attrs.enterSubmit);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, I used an isolate scope because I wanted to use the controller function to submit, but didn't know about 'scope.$apply'.
Your explanation makes sense, and it works !

Comment: @y__b__y, you can also use $eval: `scope.$eval(attrs.enterSubmit)` if you don't need a digest cycle to run.